# MariaDB fails to start after reboot - can start it manually

Tags: centos7, mariadb

I have a VPS running Centos7 with MariaDB. I am having issues trying to get it to start MariaDB on boot, I am binding MariaDB to my VPS's private address as I only want it to listen to connections on that interface. It fails with this in the logs:

```
170204 15:34:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
170204 15:34:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170204 15:34:13 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52-MariaDB) starting as process 784 ...
170204 15:34:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170204 15:34:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170204 15:34:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
170204 15:34:13 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170204 15:34:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170204 15:34:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170204 15:34:13 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170204 15:34:13  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170204 15:34:14 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.49-MariaDB-38.0 started; log sequence number 1597945
170204 15:34:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170204 15:34:14 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '10.99.0.14'.
170204 15:34:14 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 99: Cannot assign requested address
170204 15:34:14 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
170204 15:34:14 [ERROR] Aborting

170204 15:34:14  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170204 15:34:15  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1597945
170204 15:34:15 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

However, I am able to start the service manually by running `sudo systemctl start mariadb` which produces:

```
170204 15:34:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
170204 15:38:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170204 15:38:52 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52-MariaDB) starting as process 2609 ...
170204 15:38:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170204 15:38:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170204 15:38:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
170204 15:38:52 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170204 15:38:52 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170204 15:38:52 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170204 15:38:52 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170204 15:38:52  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170204 15:38:53 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.49-MariaDB-38.0 started; log sequence number 1597945
170204 15:38:53 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170204 15:38:53 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '10.99.0.14'.
170204 15:38:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
170204 15:38:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.52-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

My my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

bind-address    = 10.99.0.14

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

I **temporarily** disabled SELinux to see if this was the issue, however it didn't seem to fix the issue. It works fine when I bind to 0.0.0.0 but I don't particularly want to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by adding network-online.target to the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` file, under the unit directive:

```
[Unit]
Description=MariaDB database server
After=syslog.target
After=network-online.target
```

Originally, it was set to `network.target`.
Basically the eth1 interface wasn't getting an IP address fast enough, causing MariaDB to complain on boot.

Thanks @nickm

Answer (score 0):

In my case what it took after an upgrade from 5.5.68-MariaDB to 10.5.8 was just this (note: drupal running with mariadb on RHEL7):

```
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```

I hope this will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

This happened because your MariaDB configuration sets a `bind-address` to an IP address which is not on any interface when MariaDB starts.

```
bind-address    = 10.99.0.14
```

You can resolve this by not binding to any specific address; MariaDB will then answer on any interface or IP address, even those not present when it started. Do so by removing all instances of `bind-address =` from your configuration.

(You can also resolve it by having systemd wait to start MariaDB until the IP address is available, as shown in [another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/830542/126632).)